# JavaScript Nav Bar TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to HTML, CSS and JavaScript. I am getting the error which states: `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object`. Now I have tried to look for the issue but had no luck. Can someone help? Error occurs in the console at: item.ClassList.container('active') && handleIndicator(item);

```js
var indicator = document.querySelector('.indicator');
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item');

function handleIndicator(el) {
  items.forEach(function(el) {
    item.ClassList.remove('active');
    item.removeAttribute('style');
  });

  indicator.style.width = "".concat(el.offsetWidth, "px");
  indicator.style.left = "".concat(el.offsetLeft, "px");
  indicator.style.backgroundColor = el.getAttribute('active-color');
  el.ClassList.add('active');
  el.style.color = el.Attributes('active-color');
}

items.forEach(function(item, index) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    handleIndicator(e.target);
  });
  item.ClassList.container('active') && handleIndicator(item);
});
```

```html
<nav>
  <a class="nav-item active" active-color="red">Test 1</a>
  <a class="nav-item" active-color="blue">Test 2</a>
  <a class="nav-item" active-color="purple">Test 3</a>
  <a class="nav-item" active-color="pink">Test 4</a>
  <div class="indicator"></div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const indicator = document.querySelector('.indicator');
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item');

function handleIndicator(el) {
  items.forEach(e => {
    e.classList.remove('active');
    e.removeAttribute('style');
  });

  indicator.style.width = "".concat(el.offsetWidth, "px");
  indicator.style.left = "".concat(el.offsetLeft, "px");
  indicator.style.backgroundColor = el.getAttribute('active-color');
  el.classList.add('active');
  el.style.color = el.getAttribute('active-color')
}

items.forEach(item => {

  item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    handleIndicator(e.target);
  });
  //item.classList.contains('active') && handleIndicator(item);
});
```

```html
<nav>
  <a class="nav-item active" active-color="red">Test 1</a>
  <a class="nav-item" active-color="blue">Test 2</a>
  <a class="nav-item" active-color="purple">Test 3</a>
  <a class="nav-item" active-color="pink">Test 4</a>
  <div class="indicator"></div>
</nav>
```

Comment: many thanks that worked. Can I ask the slight changes you made, what can I read to understand better? the => over el and not using the item.classList line at the end?

Comment: You are welcome mate :) You can learn about arrow functions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 2):

`item.ClassList.remove('active');` should be `item.classList.remove('active');`. it should be in lowercase

Comment: Even though this actually solves the issue, do not answer so type of questions. Issues that are caused by typos have no value to the community. As such they should be flagged as: `not reproduciable or caused by a typo`. Those Questions then will be removed (deleted) and all awarded points reverted. I'm aware that you do not have the required 50 reputation to comment. However this is no legitimate reason to bypass the limitation by using the answer option.

Comment: @tacoshy thanks for letting me know about that flag I don't know about that feature this is my first time

Comment: Ahh thanks guys. So simple, definitely living up to my name....